# Cannot execute mvn heroku deploy

Tags: java, maven, heroku, deployment, buildpack

I am currently struggling to deploy a Spring Boot app using `mvn heroku:deploy`. When I initially try it, I am given the following error message:

`` [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:2.0.6:deploy (default-cli) on project <APP_NAME>: Failed to deploy application: Your buildpacks do not contain the heroku/jvm buildpack!Add heroku/jvm to your buildpack configuration or run `heroku buildpacks:clear`. -> [Help 1] ``

(Just to give context, my Buildpack URL during this point is `heroku/java`).

When I run `heroku buildpacks:clear` (followed by `git push heroku master`) as recommended, then attempt to deploy again, the deployment appears to work initially, but I am stuck with an infinite `Uploading build...` screen.

Any suggestions here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How big is your app? The uploading set might take a long time

Comment: With all of the dependencies and packages installed, the entire directory is about 212.6 MB. I could try running it overnight, but I wouldn't think a directory of this size should take this long.

Comment: Does it actually say `<APP_NAME>`? If so, you need to replace that in your pom.xml with the real app name, or remove it.

Comment: No, I only put that in here because I didn't feel comfortable giving the name of my app. I tried letting it run in the background for over 20 minutes, and it actually worked! Guess it was just taking a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
$ mvn heroku:deploy -Dheroku.logProgress
```

If it looks like there is no progress there must be some kind of client-side network issue. Alternatively, you can upload using [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) by running:

```
$ mvn heroku:deploy -Dheroku.curl.enabled=true
```

Make sure you have cURL installed by running `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if I just clear the buildpacks without pushing to Git then re-run `mvn heroku:deploy`, it takes a very long time but it eventually works. I just had to let it run in the background and wait for a while.